# iOS key value coding

Tags: ios, coding-style, key-value, kvc

Let's assume we have an object of type person, which has a property called name.

```
Person *p;
[p setValue:@"John" forKey:@"name"];
```

This works very nicely. What I want to do is dig deeper. Say the class person has another property called address which is of class Address and has a field called zipcode.

Is there a simpler way of assigning the zipcode from the person than this? Maybe something cleaner and clearer?

```
[[p valueForKey:@"address"] setValue:@"234567" forKey:@"zipcode"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `keyPath` should fit you requirements.

```
[p  setValue:@"234567" forKeyPath:@"address.zipcode"];
```

Check doc [NSKeyValueCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [Key-Value Coding Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html)